# VScode :The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process At line:1 char:1

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, mingw32, file-not-found

---

I am trying to set up C++ environment in VSCode ,
and I'm getting this error when I  try to run my helloworld file.

> Program 'helloworld.exe' failed to run: The process cannot access the file
> because it is being used by another processAt line:1 char:1

my tasks.json :

```
{
    "version" : "2.0.0",
                "tasks" :[
                    {
                      "type" : "cppbuild",
                      "label" : "echo",
                      "command" : "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe",
                      "args" : [
                          "-g ",

                          "-o",
                          "${workspaceFolder}\\helloworld.exe",

                      ],
                      "options" : {
                          "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}"
                      },
                      "problemMatcher" : ["$gcc"],
                      "group" : {

                          "kind" : "build",
                          "isDefault" : true
                      },
                      "detail" : "compiler: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe"

                    }
                ]
}
```

And getting an error saying "no such file or directory" when I try to debug my programme.

> Executing task: g++ -g helloworld.cpp
> g++.exe: error: helloworld.cpp: No such file or directory
> g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
> compilation terminated.
> The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command g++ -g helloworld.cpp" terminated with exit code: 1.

My launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "echo"
        }
    ]
}
```

kindly help me get rid of this error , and help me run my first c++ programme on vscode :(

thankyou.

Comment: Your first error likely means your last execution of `helloworld.exe` is still running or your antivirus has it open.

Comment: Your second error seems to be that helloworld.cpp is not in whatever folder that is `${workspaceFolder}`

Comment: @drescherjm.Yeah, thanks a lot  for your kind reply. Could you please suggest me any ways to get rid of this error:).

Comment: Looks like your tasks.json is missing source files. You should have `"${file}",` after `"-g ",` if you have a single source file or you only want to build the active file or `"${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp"` otherwise.

Comment: The documentation explains the tasks.json file here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)